# How to send an array to C++ function from Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm trying to send an NSMutableArray, or even just two strings to a function in C++ from Objective-C without success. I have no issues getting a string from C++ back to Objective-C, it's the other way around where I'm confused. Here's my code for getting a string from C++:

**WrapperClass.h**

```
#ifndef WrapperClass_hpp
#define WrapperClass_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

@interface WrapperClass : NSObject
@end

@interface WrapperClass ()
- (NSString *)getHelloString;
- (NSMutableArray *)sendInfo :(NSString *)str1 :(NSString *)str2; 

// the array above is what I want to send to C++

@end

#endif /* WrapperClass_h */
```

**WrapperClass.mm**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "WrapperClass.h"
#include "WrapperClass.h"
#include "CppClass.h"

using namespace test;

@interface WrapperClass ()
@property (nonatomic) HelloTest helloTest;
@end

@implementation WrapperClass

- (NSString *)getHelloString {
    self.helloTest = *(new HelloTest);
    std::string str = self.helloTest.getHelloString();
    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:str.c_str()];
    return result;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)sendInfo :(NSString *)str1 :(NSString *)str2 {
    std::string str1 = std::string([str1 UTF8String]);
    std::string str1 = std::string([str2 UTF8String]);
    std::array<std::string, 2> myArray = {{ str1, str2 }};

// Not sure how to send to CPP ...

}
```

**CppClass.h**

```
#ifndef Cpp_Class_h
#define Cpp_Class_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

namespace test {
    class HelloTest {
    public:
        std::string getHelloString();
    };
}
#endif
```

**CppClass.cpp**

```
std::string test::HelloTest::getHelloString() {
    std::string outString = "Hello World!";
    return outString;
}

// this code gets the string from c++, but how to 
// send two strings or an array to a function?
```

Comment: This look wrong: `*(new HelloTest)`. Hold the pointer instead.

Comment: Note that `*(new HelloTest)` is a memory leak in C++, and I'm assuming Objective-C++ doesn't have any special rules here. It allocates a `HelloTest` object on the heap, then *copies* it to the `helloTest` property, then forgets about the heap allocated object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, hold the pointer to the C++ class:

```
@interface WrapperClass ()
@property (nonatomic) HelloTest* helloTest;
@end
```

Better still consider using `std::unique_ptr<HelloTest>` to manage the memory.

Add the set method in the C++ class (implementation omitted):

```
namespace test {
    class HelloTest {
    public:
        std::string getHelloString() const;    // Add const!
        void setHelloStrings(const std::array<std::string>& strings);
    };
}
```

and pass it like this from Objective-C++:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)sendInfo :(NSString *)str1 :(NSString *)str2 {
    std::string str1 = std::string([str1 UTF8String]);
    std::string str1 = std::string([str2 UTF8String]);
    std::array<std::string, 2> myArray = {{ str1, str2 }};
    self.helloTest->setHelloStrings(myArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering. It makes sense what you've mentioned here, although when I try to run the code it says `undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test::HelloTest::setHelloStrings(std::__1::array<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, 2ul> const&)", referenced from:
      -[WrapperClass sendInfo::] in WrapperClass.o`. I've been trying to figure out why, but no luck. If you're willing I could post the code online if you have a moment.

Comment: @ctfd You need to add the implementation in `CppClass.cpp`.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing! I'm not exactly sure how to actually do that unfortunately... [I currently have this](https://pastebin.com/cyr66stA). Any tips? I did have to make a couple minor changes to the syntax of `self.helloTest->setHelloStrings(myArray);`. It didn't like the `->` for whatever reason (maybe because of the lack of implementation?), and `void setHelloStrings(const std::array<std::string>& strings)` had to add `..<std::string, 2>..)`

Comment: @ctfd Well add the method at least so it links successfully, and then think about what you want to do with the strings in the array.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong (obviously), so maybe if you have a moment would you please take a peek? [The example project](https://github.com/ideprecated/objc-cpp) shows the error. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @ctfd I cannot build that project at the moment, I'm afraid.  I could maybe look tonight.

Comment: Hehe, no worries. It's not a big project, basically only a couple more files than shown here, the other stuff in there is just xcode junk setup by default. You're awesome, cheers!

Comment: @ctfd You've missed off the namespace and classname when defining the C++ set method.  Also better is to use `namespace test { ... }` around the method definitions rather than as part of the definition signature.

Comment: That was exactly the issue; I'm not certain I know what you mean about the "around the method definitions rather than as part of the definition signature", although I'll do some searching to hopefully figure it out. I really appreciated your help, thanks again.

Comment: @ctfd I simply mean using `namespace test { ... }` around the method definitions in the `.cpp` file like you did with the declarations in the `.h` file.